# KeyError: Traceback (most recent call last), KeyError: 0

Tags: python, keyerror

I was doing Feature Selection for my dataset using the Selector Object for Selecting Features method. When I had written the following code, I received an error that said:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:

4 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805             except TypeError:
   3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 0
```

The code for which this error had occured is given below:

```
# Create a random forest classifier
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0, 
                             criterion='gini') # Use gini criterion to define feature importance

# Create a SelectFromModel object 
sfm = SelectFromModel(estimator=rfc, # Use random forest classifier to identify features
                      threshold=0.05) # that have an importance of more than 0.05

# Train the selector
sfm = sfm.fit(X_train, Y_train)

# Print the names of the most important features
print('The most important features based on random forest classifier:')
for feature_list_index in sfm.get_support(indices=True):
    print('- ' + feature_names[feature_list_index])
```

The error was showing in this line:
`print('- ' + feature_names[feature_list_index])`

Can anyone please help me with this?

I had tried to declare "feature_list_index" as a list with the following code, but still it showed me the same error.

`feature_list_index = defaultdict(list)`

Comment: Please share how `feature_names` is defined, or where you're getting it from. It appears it doesn't have an element at index `0`, but it's impossible to say why with what you shared so far.

Comment: I have defined "feature_names" in the following way:
"feature_names = parkinsons_data.drop(columns=['name','status'], axis=1)"